# Write data to Arduino from terminal (OSX)

Tags: macos, file-io, serial-port, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm attempting to send data to my Arduino over my USB cable from the OSX terminal. My understanding was that I should be able just do something like `echo b > /dev/tty.usbmodem1411` or `echo b > /dev/cu.usbmodem1411` but neither of those are working. I also tried an explicit newline by doing `echo "b\r\n" > /dev/tty.usbmodem1411` and `echo "b\r\n" > /dev/cu.usbmodem1411` but neither worked. I don't really have any idea what's going on, what the difference between the `cu` and `tty` is (when I write data with the Serial Monitor in the Arduino IDE I use the `cu` version, and that works)

Answer (score 3):

It is not as easy as `echo`ing :)

Here is great tutorial with everything you need to know about Serial Communication -- [Serial Terminal Basics](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/all)

I'd be happy to answer more of your questions if needed.

**EDIT:**

for the shell script something like that:

```
#!/bin/bsh

screen /dev/tty.usbmodem* 9600

# and everything you need to do
```

Comment: Thanks! Using that guide I managed to send data using `screen /dev/tty.usbmodem1411 9600` and exit cleanly with `ctrl+a+\` but I'd like to be able to script my interaction with the Arduino. Is that possible using screen? To just open the screen, send the data, then close, from a script?

Comment: sure! a basic `shell` script should be doable :)

Comment: How would I do that? I looked through the output of `screen -h` and didn't see how I might be able to do this, and I skimmed `man screen` and didn't see anything that was obviously relevant.

Comment: Cool, this seems promising, but I couldn't figure out what to put after the `screen` line to make it actually do stuff. No matter what I put there, I just get stuck into a `screen` session, and when I exit, it says `quit: command not found` or `-X command not found` or `stuff: command not found`

Comment: I think you have to create a *detached* `screen` session and interact with it through your shell script. I've never tried that but I'll give it a try when I get time. You could also ask this as another question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog post: http://todbot.com/blog/2006/12/06/arduino-serial-c-code-to-talk-to-arduino/

And this code: https://github.com/todbot/arduino-serial

Which solve the problem.